# Verification the integral identity $\int_0^\pi \ln(1+\alpha\cos(x))dx=\pi\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}{2}\right)$.

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to verify that

> $$\int_0^\pi \ln(1+\alpha\cos(x))dx=\pi\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}{2}\right)$$

with $|\alpha|<1$. It is my homework and don't know where to begin.

Comment: Is $\alpha$ supposed to satisfy $|\alpha| \leq 1$?

Comment: @Ned Dabby: this question is very interesting (+1).

Comment: @Ned Dabby: where does this problem come from?

Comment: @Chris'ssister: Oh sorry for the delay. This was one of the problem I had to solve. It comes from ADVANCED CALCULUS by Schaum. Thank you for +1. :-)

Comment: @Ned Dabby: no problem. I'm glad to see such questions around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$I(\alpha) = \int_0^{\pi} \ln (1+ \alpha \cos(x)) dx$$
$$\dfrac{dI}{d \alpha} = \int_0^{\pi} \dfrac{\cos(x)}{1+\alpha \cos(x)} dx = \dfrac1{\alpha} \int_0^{\pi} \dfrac{\alpha \cos(x)}{1+ \alpha \cos(x)} dx = \dfrac1{\alpha} \left( \pi - \int_0^{\pi} \dfrac{dx}{1+\alpha \cos(x)}\right)$$
And integral $$\int_0^{\pi} \dfrac{dx}{1+\alpha \cos(x)}$$ can be evaluated using the standard complex analytic technique by using the transformation $z = \exp(ix)$.

Comment: @Thank you Marvis. Now, Iknow how to begin. I know that inyegral.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Differentiate the left-hand sign with respect to $\alpha$. The details are probably in your book, but if not, there is a useful [Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) You will get something you can integrate explicitly with respect to $x$.

Compare with the derivative of the right-hand side with respect to $\alpha$. Finally, observe that the left-hand side and the right-hand side agree at $\alpha=0$.