# On $\int_0^\pi\arctan(1+\cos x)\,\mathrm{d}x\overset{?}{=}\pi\operatorname{arccot}\sqrt{\phi}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}\newcommand{\arccot}{\operatorname{arccot}}$I recently took part in a UK university integration bee (which is over, so, there is no issue posting about it). My team did pretty well but of course there were a few we didn't get; I find this one interesting in particular.

> $$J:=\int_0^\pi\arctan(1+\cos x)\d x=\pi\arccot(\sqrt{\phi})$$Where appears the golden ratio.

(well, we don't actually know what the real answer is but according to numerical reverse engineering software it checks out to $\pi\arccot(\sqrt{\phi})$ and this is just plausible enough)

Using elementary symmetries you can realise $J=\int_0^{\pi/2}\arctan(2\csc^2(x))\d x=\int_0^{\pi/2}\arctan(2\sec^2(x))\d x$ or that $J=\int_0^{\pi}\arctan(2\cos^2(x/2))\d x$. No apparent reduction in complexity. We tried differentiation under the integral sign with:

- $\int_0^\pi\arctan(\alpha(1+\cos x))\d x$
- $\int_0^\pi\arctan(\alpha+\cos x)\d x$
- $\int_0^\pi\arctan(1+\alpha\cos x)\d x$
- $\int_0^\pi\arctan(1+\cos(\alpha x))\d x$

None seemed to give anything we could work with. The only real trick up my sleeve - contour integration - is almost certainly inapplicable here.

Does anyone have any ideas? There's probably an easy way that we missed.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2252510/121671) may be helpful.

Comment: It's possibly just a coincidence, but the value of the memorable integral in this highly upvoted post is a nonzero integer multiple of the one in this post, i.e., $\pi \operatorname{arccot} \sqrt\pi$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562694/integral-int-11-frac1x-sqrt-frac1x1-x-ln-left-frac2-x22-x1

Comment: Numerical investigation suggests that we also have $\int_0^\pi\arctan(1+\sec x)\mathrm dx=\pi\operatorname{arccot}\left(\phi+\sqrt{\phi}\right)$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Expand $\tan^{-1}(y)$ via its logarithm definition:

$$\int_0^\pi\arctan(1+\cos x)dx=\frac i2\int_0^\pi\ln\left(1+\frac{1-i}2\cos(x)\right)-\ln\left(1+\frac{1+i}2\cos(x)\right)-\frac{\pi i}2dx$$

Now apply:

> [Verification of the integral identity $\displaystyle\int_0^\pi \ln(1+\alpha\cos(x))dx=\pi\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}{2}\right)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192393/verification-the-integral-identity-int-0-pi-ln1-alpha-cosxdx-pi-ln-lef)

and the principal logarithm:

$$\frac i2\int_0^\pi\ln\left(1+\frac{1-i}2\cos(x)\right)-\ln\left(1+\frac{1+i}2\cos(x)\right)-\frac{\pi i }2dx=\frac{\pi i}2\ln(-i)+\frac{\pi i}2\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{4+2i}+2}{\sqrt{4-2i}+2}\right)=\frac{\pi i} 2\ln\left(\sqrt5–2-2\sqrt{\sqrt5-2}i\right)$$

We rationalized to get the last expression. Finally use $\frac i2\ln(x)=\cot^{-1}(i\frac{x+1}{1-x})$ and rationalize again to get:

$$\int_0^\pi\arctan(1+\cos x)dx=\pi\cot^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt5+1}2}\right)=\pi\cot^{-1}(\sqrt\phi)$$

Comment: [Related result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562694/integral-int-11-frac1x-sqrt-frac1x1-x-ln-left-frac2-x22-x1)

Comment: This question was proposed by me for the bee, and this was my exact solution. Nice!

Answer (score 8):

Let $I(a)= \int_0^{\pi/2} \tan^{-1}(\sinh a \cos^2x)dx$
\begin{align}
I’(a)=&\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cosh a \cos^2x}{1+\sinh^2a\cos^4x}dx\\
= &\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cosh a \sec^2x}{(1+\tan^2x)^2+\sinh^2a}dx=\frac\pi4\text{sech}\frac a2
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
&\int_0^\pi\tan^{-1}(1+\cos x)dx\\ = &\ 2I(\sinh^{-1}2)=2\int_0^{\sinh^{-1}2}I’(a)da
= \frac\pi2 \int_0^{\sinh^{-1}2}\text{sech}\frac a2\ da\\
=&\  \pi \cot^{-1}\left( \text{csch}\frac a2\right)\bigg|_0^{\sinh^{-1}2}
=\pi \cot^{-1}\sqrt{\phi}
\end{align}

Comment: How would you evaluate $I’(a)$?

Comment: Mysterious (but supremely elegant as always). Mind explaining why you tried an integrating factor of $\sinh a$?

Comment: @FShrike - I tried a simple parameter $a$ to begin with and got a complicated $I’(a)$, which simplifies to $\text{sech}\frac a2$ under $a\to \sinh a$.

Comment: @ТymaGaidash - with the substitution $t=\tan x$

Comment: Thanks!${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Wow this is a really nice solution!